# youtube-dl error outdated python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

when i try to download content from vrtnu.be, youtube-dl always returns the same error. Can somebody help me?

```
youtube-dl -v --username janvankerckhoven@gmail.com --password xxxxxx -fmp4 https://www.vrt.be/vrtnu/a-z/een-kwestie-van-geluk/seizoen-1/een-kwestie-van-geluk-d20180121-sseizoen-1a1/
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'-v', u'--username', u'PRIVATE', u'--password', u'PRIVATE', u'-fmp4', u'https://www.vrt.be/vrtnu/a-z/een-kwestie-van-geluk/seizoen-1/een-kwestie-van-geluk-d20180121-sseizoen-1a1/']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2018.03.14
[debug] Python version 2.7.5 (CPython) - Darwin-13.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 3.4.2, ffprobe 3.4.2
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[VrtNU] Logging in
[VrtNU] Requesting a token
[VrtNU] een-kwestie-van-geluk-d20180121-sseizoen-1a1: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure> (caused by URLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'),))
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 519, in _request_webpage
    return self._downloader.urlopen(url_or_request)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2199, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 1101, in https_open
    req, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
```

I updated Python using`brew upgrade python`
and I installed python 3.6.4 with an installer from python.org, but that didn't change anything.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: youtube-dl is raising a URL error, indicating a problem with the URL string you've given it. Don't worry too much about which version of Python is being used. Python 2.7 is still used all over the place for various reasons.

Comment: Found the answer here:https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5193
"pip3 install -U youtube_dl" did it for me. Its working now.